# Word meaning to judge something as having little or no worth

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm almost certain there's an English word, possibly archaic, for judging something (or someone) as having negligible worth. It might be a verb, or perhaps an adjective describing someone who does this. As I vaguely recall, it has four or more syllables. Please could someone enlighten me.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *floccinaucinihilipilificate* means exactly that.  It is a concaténation of the following:  Latin words:

- floccum means a straw.  flocci is its genitive, and in this context is a genitive of value and so means ‘worth a straw’ and so ‘worthless’.
- N’aucun means a nutshell and so nauci means worth a nutshell.
- Similarly ‘nihil’ means ‘nothing’ and so nihili means worth nothing;
- ‘Pili’ means worth a hair.

‘-fication’ is Latinate ending as in ‘modification’.   So it means exactly what you need.

The word was used in the 18th century by William Shenstone.

Comment: *The word was used in the 18th century by William Shenstone*, and never since except in quiz shows or remonstrations to avoid using it!

Comment: You are right of course.  Except the Indian writer Shashi Tharoor, in a book on Modi, thevPrine Minister of India.

Comment: I probably did hear it in a quiz show! Probably QI. Thank you Tuffy.

Answer (score 2):

A verb with *four* syllables is [**trivialize**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trivialize):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : to make trivial : reduce to triviality
> // The news story *trivialized* the problem.
> // He is *trivializing* the situation.
>
> [*trivial*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trivial)
> **1 a** : of little worth or importance
> // a *trivial* objection
> // *trivial* problems

So, when you *trivialize* something, you judge it as, or make it to be as, having little worth or importance.

---

A related four-syllable word, which applies in a more specific sense, is [**marginalize**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marginalize):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : to relegate (see [RELEGATE sense 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relegate)) to an unimportant or powerless position within a society or group
> We are protesting policies that *marginalize* women.

Barring context that isn't in the question itself, *trivialize* is the more general term, and it will apply to a wider range of situations. But *marginalize* can be more appropriate in the right context—if you're talking about trivializing something in the additional sense of making them actively unworthy of notice or effect.

Comment: I especially like *trivialize*. Perfect.